# error: Pandas requires version '1.4.16' or newer of 'sqlalchemy' (version '0.9.8' currently installed)

Tags: python, django, api, error-handling

I am using sqlalchemy to access my sql database and making changes in sql database,
the code for the requirement is:

```
output_db_engine=create_engine(
            "mssql+pymssql://{user}:{pw}@{ip}/{db}".format(
                user=PORTAL_DB_USERNAME, pw=urllib.parse.quote_plus(PORTAL_DB_PASSWORD), db=smartsearch_db_name,
                ip=smartsearch_db_ip
            )
        )
        final_df.insert(loc=0, column='Id', value=np.arange(1, len(final_df) + 1))
        final_df.to_sql('Smart_Search_Table', con=output_db_engine,
                        chunksize=900,
                        method='multi', if_exists='replace', index=False)
        # Making Id column as Primary Key in table
        with output_db_engine.connect() as con:
            con.execute('ALTER TABLE ' + 'Smart_Search_Table' + ' ALTER COLUMN Id INT NOT NULL')
            con.execute('ALTER TABLE ' + 'Smart_Search_Table' + ' ADD PRIMARY KEY (Id);')
        print(
            f"SUCCESS : Table with name Smart_Search_Table is created and loaded with new data "
        )
        return final_df

if __name__ == "__main__":
    i = making_table()
    i.making_final_df()
```

But i am getting an error:
ImportError: Unable to find a usable engine; tried using: 'sqlalchemy'.
A suitable version of sqlalchemy is required for sql I/O support.
Trying to import the above resulted in these errors:

- Pandas requires version '1.4.16' or newer of 'sqlalchemy' (version '0.9.8' currently installed).

Can anyone help me to resolve this error?

I am also getting a warning:
A NumPy version >=1.16.5 and <1.23.0 is required for this version of SciPy (detected version 1.24.1
warnings.warn(f"A NumPy version >={np_minversion} and <{np_maxversion}".

I am new to python, can anyone help me how to resolve these versions mismatch error?

Comment: pip install -U SQLAlchemy

Comment: Change the version in the requirements.txt like SQLAlchemy==1.4.36